# Create a new environment in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am not an experienced Rails developer, developing a **Rails v2.3** application with **MySQl** v5.1 .

I am not sure how to achieve the following thing:

I need to create:

**1.** A new environment (that's a new environment besides **development**,
**production** and **test** environments) named '**special**' environment

**2.** A new database environment for above created **special** environment , what I did is to add the following thing in *config/database.yml*

```
special:
   adapter: mysql2
   host: localhost
   username: 
   database: special_db
   encoding: latin1
```

**3.** A **rake task** to run under the **special** environment and the code in the rake task only deal with the **special** database.

To achieve this, I know I need to define some configurations, but not sure:

1. What/How exactly are needed to configure to create the **special** environment & database?

   (As you saw above, I only defined the **special** database in *database.yml* file, but where & how to define and configuration for the new enverionment?)
2. How to run the rake task code under the **special** environment and only deal with the special database in Rails. Could someone please

**P.S.**

I need to run everything in a rake task not from command line. How to change environment and how to check the change?

--------------Found reason, but not sure the solution---------------------

Ok, I found the reason of this wired problem is because of the `mysql2` gem which seems can not load the new "**special**" environment, if I switch to use `mysql` gem , the problem will be gone. But this probject has to use mysql2 for some other reason. How to get rid of this `mysql2` problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

Copy the config/environments/development.rb to config/environments/special.rb

Create the database using

```
 $ RAILS_ENV=special rake db:create
 $ RAILS_ENV=special rake db:migrate
 $ RAILS_ENV=special rails s
```

Comment: @ map7, thank you, but How to run the above things in a rake task instead of running from command line? Is there any special way in Rails to specify the environment to run in rake task?

Comment: And I even I run the command on "RAILS_ENV=special rake db:create" command line, the sepcial database is not created

Answer (score 1):

Put this into your rake task:

```
RAILS_ENV = 'special'
```

Comment: I added this, then I tried to out put my current environment with code "p ENV['RAILS_ENV']" , I got nil...